# Program to check if we can make odd sum out of numbers

Tags: c++, sum

So basically this program takes several test cases which consist of a sequence of numbers (of length n). It's supposed to see that, if there exists at least one combination of length x out of the sequence, so that their sum will be odd. It's enough for just one of such combinations to exist. If it's possible, we print "Yes", otherwise "No".

For example, if we input
1 (t=1, one test case)
3 2 (n=3, aka 3 total nrs, x=2, aka consider any 2 of these)
16 11 12 (these are the numbers)

2 even nrs, 1 odd. 11+12 is odd, so the output will be Yes.
[image]

**My problem** is this case particularly

```
3 3
101 102 103
```

If I check it on its own, meaning just this one test case, it outputs the correct "No".
If it's with other test cases, meaning it's test 2 or lower, it outputs "Yes".

Can anyone tell me why?
I would really appreciate it.

Here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t, n, x, k, c_even{ 0 }, c_odd{ 0 };
    string v{"No\n"};
    cin >> t;
    //t is the number of total cases
    for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++)
    {
        c_even = 0; //counter for even numbers
        c_odd = 0; // counter for odd numbers
        cin >> n >> x; // n is the total length of the sequence of nrs, x is how many numbers we consider out of the sequence

        //this for loop is for introducing the sequence and counting how many nrs are odd and even
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            cin >> k;
            if (k % 2 == 0)
                c_even++;
            else c_odd++;
        }
        
        //obv if there are no odd nrs, sum won't ever be odd
        if (c_odd == 0)
            v = "No\n";

        /*
        for example, say we have 5 odd numbers, 3 even, and we have to consider 5 numbers out of total 8.
        the for loop starts with 1. it checks if 1+3>=5, meaning if we have enough even nrs to make odd sum. it's not correct in this case.
        then it goes to o=3; it checks if 3+3>=5. correct! so we have enough even nrs to make odd sum. other cases don't have to be considered.
        */
        else for (int o = 1; o <= c_odd; o += 2)
        {
            if (o + c_even >=x)
            {
                v = "Yes\n";
                break;
            }
        }
        cout << v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just move `string v{"No\n"};` inside the outermost loop. Otherwise, the way the `if-else` is structured, you might accidentally use the value from the previous iteration.

Comment: My god, you're right. I didn't even realize it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @davaisk This is why you write functions to do the test, and not stick everything inside of `main`.  Calling a function to do the test eliminates these types of errors.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for the advice. This is my second week of C++ and in general, programming. I still have much more to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Just had to move `string v{"No\n"};` inside the first for. 
As [cigien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8372853/cigien) said, if `string v{"No\n"};` is outside the first loop, in case one iteration sets v as "Yes" and the next one does not satisfy

```
if (c_odd == 0)
            v = "No\n";
```

in other words, the v remains "Yes", the program will output automatically "Yes", although it is not the correct answer.
By moving that bit of code inside the first for, we assure that each iteration will start with v as "No".

Comment: The answer will be a lot more useful if you explain *why* this is necessary.

Comment: The long term solution is to not stuff everything inside of `main`, and instead create a function that runs the test.